# Inferring the number of topics for gensim's LDA - perplexity, CM, AIC, and BIC

Tags: aic, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc, latent-class, perplexity

I am confused as to how to interpret the LDA's perplexity fluctuations with different numbers of topics, in the endeavour of determining the best number of topics. Additionally, I would like to know how to implement AIC/BIC with gensim LDA models.

I am importing the 20 newsgroups dataset from [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html):

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups;
```

Metadata were removed as per sklearn recommendation, and the data were split to test and train using sklearn also (`subset` parameter).

I trained 35 LDA models with different values for k,  the number of topics, ranging from 1 to 100, using the train subset of the data. Afterwards, I estimated the per-word perplexity of the models using gensim's multicore LDA `log_perplexity` function, using the test held-out corpus::

```
DLM_testCorpusBoW = [DLM_fullDict.doc2bow(tstD) for tstD in testData];    
PerWordPP = modelLDA.log_perplexity(DLM_testCorpusBoW);
```

Eventually, keeping in mind that true k is **20** for the used dataset, perplexity figures were startling negative ones:

[image]

Additionally, I implemented [Topic Coherence Models](https://rare-technologies.com/what-is-topic-coherence/), and the results weren't very informative, with a lot of fluctuation:

[image]
[image]

Having negative perplexity apparently is due to infinitesimal probabilities being converted to the log scale automatically by Gensim, but even though a lower perplexity is desired, the lower bound value denotes deterioration (according to [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gensim/iK692kdShi4/VsLvnetsesIJ)), so the lower bound value of perplexity is **deteriorating** with a larger number of topics in my figures, yet we expect the perplexity to improve with a bigger k ([here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gensim/TpuYRxhyIOc/fRrO260Jc-MJ)).

So, do the figures seem logical?
And I would like to implement AIC and BIC as well, but for that I need the [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) of the models, how can I get it using gensim? or are these measures implemented somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Counter intuitively, it appears that the [`log_perplexity`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.log_perplexity) function doesn't output a $perplexity$ after all (the documentation of the function wasn't clear enough for me personally), but a likelihood $bound$ which must be utilised in the perplexity's lower bound equation thus (Taken from [this paper](https://endymecy.gitbooks.io/spark-ml-source-analysis/content/%E8%81%9A%E7%B1%BB/LDA/docs/Online%20Learning%20for%20Latent%20Dirichlet%20Allocation.pdf) - **Online Learning for Latent Dirichlet Allocation** by *Hoffman, Blei and Bach*):
$$
perplexity (n^{test}, \lambda, \alpha) \leq exp\{
-(\sum_i{
\mathbb{E}_q [log_p(n_i^{test}, \theta_i, z_i | \alpha, \beta)]
-
\mathbb{E}_q[log_q(\theta_i, z_i)])
/
(\sum_{i,w}{n_{iw}^{test}})
}
\}
$$

Viz.,

$$
perplexity (n^{test}, \lambda, \alpha) \leq e^{- bound}
$$

Some people like to use $2$ instead of $e$ in the equation above.

For calculating $AIC$ and $BIC$, one usually needs the Bayesian likelihood of the model, not necessarily the $SSE$, especially in a topic modelling environment.

Finally, as for the $U Mass$ coherence measure, to the best of my knowledge, it hasn't been used in a model selection scenario with LDA yet, but the sharp dip I got at $k=20$ (the *proper* number of topics according to the 20 newsgroups dataset) is encouraging. However, topic coherence measures should be close to zero optimally, so that sharp dip isn't an improvement, rather a deterioration in the coherence (the meaningfulness or interpretability) of topics.